# Unable to find optional library: org.apache.http.legacy

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, apache-commons-httpclient

Tried everything from stackoverflow. I have listed below all that I tried to rectify this error : (I know there are lot of answers for this. It's still isn't working for me)

1. Checked for the presence of the .json file (check)
2. Add the "useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'" to app module gradle file (check)
3. Add the .jar file from the sdk location to libs (check)
4. Reinstall API 23 (check)
5. Right click the jar from libs folder and add to library (check)
6. Change location to avoid 256 characters. (check)
7. add "compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])" to gradle file dependencies (was present by default) (check)

That is pretty much everything from all the answers. Can anyone please provide a soltuion? I have been on this for 10 hours; Reinstalling and changing scripts.

My Gradle :

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.name"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.0.0-alpha1'
}
```

Comment: @pRaNaY sry. check the edit. it was there. Another one of trials suggested was to remove the useLibrary and just keep the compile. That failed too. that's why it was missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve the Warning message

```
    Unable to find optional library: org.apache.http.legacy
```

By upgrading my Android studio. It was 1.3.2 . Now it is 2.2.

Answer (score 1):

For me I use this and it work:

```
android {
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy' // put it in here
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.name"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I was able to get rid of the error from gradle. However, the classes using Apache are still not readable, the import statements are not working. so, its more like the library wasn't loaded properly.

Comment: Can you try to validate caches and restart your android studio? Am I right? you are using android studio?

Comment: Can you explain what do you mean by validate caches please? And only the apache classes are still throwing the errors. Others are fine.

Comment: I will post it in another question, now that this warning is solved.

Comment: @LakshmiNarayanan have you solved error or not? and compile your project?

Comment: @dipali the error/warning has disappeared. But am still not able to use the apache classes.

Answer (score 1):

First of all make sure to use this gradle plugin or higher:

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.1'
```

Then check if the `Android/Sdk/platforms/android-23/optional` folder contains the `optional.json` file.

A good idea is to use the latest version :

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.0'
```

Without this version you will not able to handle with the `useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'`

It is non related with your issue, but also check your dependencies and the api used to compile.

```
android {

     compileSdkVersion 24
     //....
}
dependencies {
      compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
      compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
}
```